# Is a html table within a table valid?

Tags: html

In html, is it valid to have a table inside of a table?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Literally it would be very tedious to achieve, but with HTML it's absolutely fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i google table within table, just show me with tutorial. Thanks for the confirm!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, perfectly valid.

By pasting what you have into the W3C validator, the only errors are regarding doctype, head tags, etc... nothing ever mentioned of nesting table within table (even after adding all the correct tags that it errored on) It suggests using a `tbody`

http://validator.w3.org/check