# Hierarchical Grid in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make a hierarchical data table with angularjs.
For example, it can lower the table and took a table in the first row of the table.
How can I create nested tables this event ?
I wrote how I wanted to do something as an example below.

Please hepl me! Thank you.
**Example:**

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Head 1</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>Content 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td style="margin-left: 10px">
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>Head 1.1</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Content 1.1</td>
              </tr>
                   <table>
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                             <th></th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          <tr>
                           <td>Content 1.1.1</td>
                         </tr>
                      </tbody>
                   </table>
             </tbody>
            </table>
     </td> 
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: consider adding the json data example and try adding a plunkr example which would show where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

*First of all* - Table in Tables is valid html (see: [Is a html table within a table valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764070/is-a-html-table-within-a-table-valid))

*Second of all* - What is the real question here? You need a controller storing the data you want to display. You can iterate with **ng-repeat** to get the structure.

It looks like you want to display a Table of Contents. A list is a better option here:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="TableController">
  <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="c in content">
    {{c.header}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="cc in c.content">{{cc}}</li>      
    </ul>  
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module("tableApp", []);
app.controller("TableController", ["$scope",function($scope){
        $scope.content = [
        { header: "Head 1", content: ["Content 1"]},
        { header: "Head 1.1", content: ["Content 1.1", "Content 1.1.1"]}
    ];
}]);

// See: https://jsfiddle.net/6se8xq41/
```

[see example here](https://jsfiddle.net/6se8xq41/)

Comment: Thanks. But 
Create dynamic content will be. :(

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic content?

Comment: The need to create a dynamic table.

Comment: I dont see the problem?